# How to turn a 2dimensional program into 1dimensional?

Tags: python, while-loop

My professor asked me to make a two-dimensional program that would count a student's average. Now he said he wants me to turn my hardwork into a one dimensional program and I have no idea how to do so, any help?

```
import sys
    students = []
    grades = []

    while True:
        student = input ("Enter a name: ").replace(" ","")
        if  student.isalpha() == True and student != "0":
            while True:
                grade = input("Enter a grade: ").replace(" ","")
                if grade == "0" or grade == 0:
                    print ("\n")
                    print ("A zero is entered.")
                    sys.exit(0)
                if grade.isdigit()== True: 
                    grade = int(grade)
                    if grade >= 1 and grade <= 10:
                        if student in students:
                            index = students.index(student)
                            grades[index].append(grade)
                            break
                        else:
                            students.append(student)
                            grades.append([grade])
                            break
                    else:
                        print("Invalid grade.")
        elif student == "0": 
            print("A zero is entered.")
            break
        else:
            print ("Invalid name.")
    for i in range(0,len(students)): 
        print("NAME: ", students[i])
        print("GRADE: ", grades[i])
        print("AVERAGE: ", round(sum(grades[i])/len(grades[i]),1), "\n")
```

For example, right now it prints out:

```
NAME:  Jack
GRADE:  [8, 7, 9]
AVERAGE:  8.0
```

But I need it to print out like this:

```
NAME:  Jack
GRADE:  8, 7, 9
AVERAGE:  8.0
```

Comment: Did he explain what "two-dimensional program" means? I've never seen it used before and have no idea what it means.

Comment: @KSFT As I understood he wants the program to print out simple numbers like for example `8, 9, 7` because right now it prints out `[8] [9] [7]` and using a function that would delete the [] is not a way to go around apparently.

Comment: My guess is that the 2 arrays ``students, grades`` could be turned into 1 array of records (or however it is called in python) containing ``name,  grade`` entries.

Comment: @KSFT: My guess is that by "one-dimensional" the prof means one list that contains pairs of elements that each represent one student and their grade. i.e. `[('Susan', 95), ('Tom', 90), ...]`. OP can you confirm this?

Comment: yeah i'd go with that you can do it with one array instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think that replacing `grades.append([grade])` with `grades.append(grade)` would help.</s>

Okay, I think I understand your question better now. Try printing like this:

```
print("GRADE: ", ", ".join(grades[i]))
```

Comment: If I do that, then I cannot enter 3 grades or more. Only two.